# AspectJ Injection in Vaadin working only after I Generate the SerialVersionID

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, aspectj, vaadin

Hi I am using Spring 3 + Spring MVC (half of the site) + Vaadin + AspectJ + JPA2 + Spring Security

My problem is that Spring creates all my Repositories and I would like to share those with Vaadin using AspectJ injection with Spring Annotations, when vaadin is started (Admin part of the site)

I have managed to make it all working after a couple days, I can use the @Configurable Spring annotation in my Vaadin Controller so It can get auto injected with my Spring context repositories,

BTW I am using Compile-Time weaving with maven, codehaus plugins and AspectJ eclipse plugin so tomcat can get the necessary libs.

BUT...

It sometimes works sometimes doesn't...

**I found that when I add serializable interface to my repos it works, but only If I ask  to generate the serialId and then  run the app (tomcat) right after it, if I make any changes and build it again, injection is gone.**

My config and Classes...

part that I think matters of my applicationContext.xml

```
   .
   .
   Other stuff

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.gsc" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

   .
   .
   Other stuff
```

here is the Vaadin Servlet

```
package br.com.gsc.vaadin;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

import br.com.gsc.model.tableMapping.Person;
import br.com.gsc.repository.objRepos.PersonRepository;

import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;


@Configurable(preConstruction=true,autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public class VaadinOperatorServlet extends Application {


/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1481084776783567319L;

    @Autowired
    private transient PersonRepository pRepo;

    public void init() {
        createWindow();
    }

    public void createWindow(){
        Window window = new Window();
        Panel p = new Panel();
        Label l = new Label("Teste");
        Label l2 = new Label("");
        Label l3 = new Label("");

        Person person = pRepo.findPersonByID("user");
        l2 = new Label(person.getUsername());
        p.addComponent(l);
        p.addComponent(l2);
        window.addComponent(p);
        setMainWindow(window);
        window.getContent().setSizeFull();  
    }
}
```

My Repo

```
package br.com.gsc.repository.objRepos;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.gsc.model.tableMapping.Person;
import br.com.gsc.repository.AbsRepository;
import br.com.gsc.repository.objInterfaces.IPersonRepository;

@Repository
public class PersonRepository extends AbsRepository<Person> implements IPersonRepository,Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8520715359024018210L;

    @Override
    public void addPerson(Person t) {
        add(t);
    }

    Lot's of other stuff....



}
```

Web.xml with the servlet routings and other stuff.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>GSC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/intern.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

<!-- Vaadin production mode -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

<!--    SERVLETS     -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.gsc.vaadin.VaadinOperatorServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>Application widgetset</description>
            <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.gsc.vaadin.widgetset.GscWidgetset</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<!--    SERVLET MAPPINGS -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/oper/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>   
    <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>        

<!--  Filter OpenSession     -->   
    <filter>  
      <filter-name>openEntityManager</filter-name>   
      <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>   
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>  
      <filter-name>openEntityManager</filter-name>   
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   
    </filter-mapping>  
<!--  Filter OpenSession  -->

    <!--  Filter Security  -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--  Filter Security -->

    <!-- Filter HTTP Methods -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Filter HTTP Methods -->
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could not fix it by any means...

I finally used Spring roo to build a maven web app and pasted all my codes and configs there, because I knew Roo worked out of the box with Aspects.

It's now working... but I have no clue why my last project had that issue with DI outside Spring Context.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem we had, where we had correctly configured maven to compile-time weave our @Configurable's, but Eclipse did not do this automatically.
This is a feature of the m2eclipse plugin in eclipse that's lacking I think.
Because you correctly define the spring-aspects jar in the aspects path in the pom file, but eclipse doesn't know to do this as well. 
So we had to manually add the AOP facet to your project that contains @Configurables, and then configure it to add the spring-aspects.jar as the aspects path.
Then when eclipse compiles, the aspects are woven, and when you run your tomcat from Eclipse, your tomcat will use woven classes, instead of non-woven classes.